# i am getting this error "Cannot find module '/var/app/current/src/server.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry"

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, package.json

I am getting this error when i deploy a node project to Elastic Beanstalk after that i changed this code

```
main: src/server.js
```

to

```
main: server.js
```

in the package.json file then i deleted every src keyword from the whole file.
now the amazon relational database service RDS gets connected, the server runs for a moment and they get disconnected as i can see in the log.
this is what's in the folder i try to upload

```
config
controllers
.npmrc
aws.js
aws.js.map
package.json
sequalize.js
sequalize.js.map
server.js
server.js.map
```

these are the inbound rules of RDS

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUSHF.png

so what do you suggest?